# Menu and Submene hide/show functions

Tags: jquery

Hey guys so I have this code below and it works fine. But what i want to happen is when "#flip" is open and i click "#slides", "#flip" sub menu will close while #slides opens. Currently everything I click will remain open.
Thank you,

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#flip").click(function(){
$(".panel").slideToggle();
});
$("#slides").click(function(){
$(".slide").slideToggle();
});
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="flip">Ladders</div>
<div class="panel"><a href="HTMLPage2.html">Home</a></div>
<div class="panel"><a href="HTMLPage.html">Home2</a></div>

<div id="slides">Slides</div>
<div class="slide"><a href="HTMLPage2.html">Home</a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="HTMLPage.html">Home</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#flip").click(function () {
    $(".panel").slideToggle();
    $(".slide").slideUp();
});
$("#slides").click(function () {
    $(".slide").slideToggle();
    $(".panel").slideUp();
});
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/ZMh3B/